# Node.js - Pegar valores de input?

Tags: node.js

Lá vou eu de novo. Tenho uma função onde se efetua um cadastro no banco de dados MySQL ela está funcionando. Mas ao tentar pegar os dados de um input recebo o seguinte erro:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'user' of undefined

Node:

```
exports.AddUser = function(request, reponse){
    console.log('Email: ', reponse.body.user.email);
    Model.addUser({email_usuario: Math.random() , senha_usuario:'sds' }, function(user){
        reponse.render('user/add', {
            title: 'cadastro'
        });
    }); 
};
```

Jade:

```
extends ../layout
block content
form(action="../user/add", method="post")
    label Email
    input(type="text" name="user[email]")
    label senha
    input(type="password" name="user[senha]")
    button(type="submit") Cadastrar
br
```

já tentei com `reponse.body.email` , `input(type="text" name="senha")` e não funcionou, o que está de errado aqui?

Comment: Em que linha te dá esse erro?

Comment: Ao invés de `reponse.body.email`, utilize o `request.body.email`

Comment: Opa pessoal, consegui resolver e apenas tive que colocar o módulo 'body-parser' e colocando esse código 'app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var express = require("express"),
    http = require("http"),
    path = require("path"),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app = express();

app.set('port', 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')));


require('./router')(app);

http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){
   console.log('Running');
});
```

Apenas adicionei o módulo 'body-parser' e adicionei este trecho

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));


   console.log('Email: ', request.body.nome);
```